# KD tree where two points have a same dimension (2d)

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree, nearest-neighbor

Let us assume to have a simple 2D case where we have a set of points.
Now let us assume that two of these points have the same value on one of the dimension, e.g., the x-dimension.

During the "splitting" phase, what happens if I'm splitting on the x-axis on these two points? How should I consider this case?

Answer (score 0):

Equal points have to go to one of the sides, you can choose which side, but you have to be consistent. I usually use "<" for "left" and ">=" for right.

Be careful that you implement the same "<" vs ">=" during queries.